# Firebase functions CORS not doing anything

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, cors

I'm creating a Firebase cloud function to send a notification to users. I want only a particular domain and all its subdomains to be able to access the onRequest method.

```
import { onRequest } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import { setGlobalOptions } from "firebase-functions/v2/options";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

setGlobalOptions({ maxInstances: 10 });

export const sendPersonalNotification = onRequest({ cors: [/domain\.com$/] }, async (req, res) => {
    // REST OF MY CODE HERE
});
```

The function is working as expected, but anybody is able to open the URL to access this function, I want to limit it to just domain.com and its subdomains. Technically, sending from my local machine shouldn't work then right?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. CORS means cross-origin and is enforced in web browsers. The target only supplies CORS headers. The target does not enforce anything. Anyone from anywhere can make a direct request to your endpoint. CORS works because most of the world uses web browsers to access content. However, it is not a security protection mechanism outside the browser.

Comment: @JohnHanley CORS isn't even a protection _in_ the browser; the Same-Origin Policy is.

Comment: @jub0bs - please clarify your comment. The browser enforces CORS for cross-origin requests, I am not aware of any other application that does.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't know of non-browser user agents that implement the SOP or CORS; that wasn't my claim. Rather, my point is that [_CORS is not a defence_](https://twitter.com/annevk/status/948831079649169408) (dixit the guy who designed CORS). CORS's only purpose is to instruct browsers to relax some restrictions that are by default enforced by the SOP. All other things being equal, activating CORS on your server makes your users less (not more) secure.

Comment: @jub0bs - What am I missing? I do not see how your comment to me is relevant to what I commented. If you are trying to correct something, clearly state what is wrong in my comment.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry if I wasn't clear. This is the part of your comment I was reacting to: _[CORS] is not a security protection mechanism outside the browser._ My point is that, even _in_ browsers, CORS isn't a "security protection mechanism".

Comment: @jub0bs - OK, I see your point, but you should direct comments to the OP. I don't have enough room to point out all of the strengths and weaknesses of CORS. My comment was to clearly point out that the OP had incorrect assumptions and to indicate further research and understanding of CORS is required.